# What is the relation between "bucket" and database and collection in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

From https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/#gridfs-collections

> GridFS places the collections in a common bucket by prefixing each
> with the bucket name. By default, GridFS uses two collections with a
> **bucket** named fs:
>
> - fs.files
> - fs.chunks

In MongoDB, is it correct that a collection is directly contained in a database?

Is it correct that in the quote, the two collections are contained directly in a bucket named `fs`?

What is a "bucket"? Is it the same concept as a database in MongoDB? Is `fs` both a bucket and a database?

```
$ mongo test
MongoDB shell version: 3.1.7
connecting to: test
Welcome to the MongoDB shell.
> db.fs.files.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("560cf6ab73f0fc3ab9000001"), "chunkSize" : 261120, 
"uploadDate" : ISODate("2015-10-01T09:02:35.397Z"), "length" : 938969, "md5" : 
"7e2877e5dad6e8e97b0fa43d28f2feca", "filename" : "/tmp/dictionary" }
>
```

Does the example above imply that a bucket `fs` is a concept between a database and a collection?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

GridFS is a specification that allows for storing documents larger than 16MB.

While the usage of the terms "bucket" in the documentation is a bit unclear, you can see it as the **prefix** for 2 collections that hold information about your documents.

It is fine to write a query like this since [there is no restriction on having collections names with a dot character](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/limits/#Restriction-on-Collection-Names).

```
 db.sample.one.insert({a:2})
```

What the [GridFS specification](https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/master/source/gridfs/gridfs-spec.rst) does provide is a work around the document size limit of `MongoDb` using database drivers. 
It defines two collections (`files` and `chunks`) with the same prefix (the default being `fs`). 
Drivers can be implemented following that for any programming language to manage large documents.